# Como mandar un arreglo o un dato por url en js?

Tags: javascript, html5

Quiero mandar un arreglo o en el peor caso solamente el un numero cuando estoy redireccionando a otra pagina esto lo hago por medio de una función de js. lo que hace ahi es que cuando le das click a un botón de la datatable te redireccione a otra pagina pero antes recupera la información del row donde le diste click esa informacion quiero que llegue a la otra pagina como le puedo hacer?

```
 $('#myTable tbody').on('click', 'button', function () {
        var data = dataTable.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
        console.log(data);
        window.location.href = "../Entrega-unidades?$data";
    });
```

Esto es lo que tenia en la otra pagina pero no tiene valores.

```
 const valores = window.location.search;

            //Mostramos los valores en consola:
            console.log(valores);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No es recomendable mandar ese tipo de información por URL, pero se puede convertir el objeto a base 64 y luego recibirlo como parametro de la url

```
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
const objectJS = JSON.stringify(arr)
const base64String = window.btoa(objectJS)
window.location.href = `../Entrega-unidades?obj=${base64String}`;
```

desde la pagina donde se recibe el valor en tu caso Entrega-unidades

```
const url = new URL(window.location.href)
const base64String = url.searchParams.get('obj')
const objectJs = window.atob(base64String)
const arr = JSON.parse(objectJs) // [1,2,3,4,5]
```